# MapKit Objects not released

Tags: ios, ios7

I am working on an app that uses MapKit, and I have run into a peculiar memory management issue. It appears some MapKit objects are not released. What could be causing this and how can I fix it? If you need code, please tell me.

The retained objects are: MKLayer, MKAnnotationViewController, MKModernUserLocationView, MKPinAnnotationView, MKNewAnnotationContainerView, _MKAnnotationViewAnchor, MKPinAnnotationViewInternal, and MKPopoverBasedAnnotationCalloutController.

Comment: sample code is almost always useful, what have your tried?

Comment: I tried to remove my references to the map view. Additionally, I made sure to remove all my annotations before the view disappears. I will post my code when I get to wifi.

Comment: There is not enough information here to show that you actually have a memory management issue. `1.`Post a screenshot of the allocations output from instruments. `2.` Edit your question to detail the exact problem you are having and the expected behaviour you were expecting. `3.`Post the code where you have the variables / properties holding onto the root objects.

Comment: Not to worry. I solved the problem fairly simply. Thanks anyways.